# Vaadin - Update UI data every second with data fetched from database

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin, vaadin7

There is a FieldGroup, whose datasource is set to an SQLContainer which is configured to use PostgreSQL database with a FreeformQuery. Another application (not webapp) writes data to a database every second.

How do I make my FieldGroup update with new data immediately? What I tried to do is setting up a ScheduledExecutorService which would get the data from the database every second and set it to a FieldGroup. But it doesn't seem to work - ScheduledExecutorService successfully gets the data from the database, but the UI isn't updated. There are no exceptions, the UI just doesn't change.

Here is the code for my ScheduledExecutorService:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SQLContainer latestData = DatabaseHelper.getLatestData();
                fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(latestData.getItem(id));
            }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have also tried to show a Notification from ScheduledExecutorService `Notification.show("hello");`
But it has no effect - the notification isn't displayed. So, maybe, it's not possible to change the UI from other than main thread?

So, once again, how to make my UI update with a new data from the database every second? Is it possible to get data not every second, but when there is a change in the database? I have also read about push from server to a client - can it help to solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, you need server push and at the same time you need to correctly synchronize access to the vaddin UI elements. Look ad the wiki+book of vaadin for this

Comment: Thanks! I have also found that another way of doing this is using poll(). I just added setPollInterval(1000); in the init() of my UI class and didn't make any changes to my ScheduledExecutorService, and it worked, the ui is updated every second. Do you have any idea what is better from the performance point of view?

Comment: When you have 1-10 clients, then this gives you additional 10requests/second on the server. If you have 1000 clients, then you receive 1000 additional requests/second. If you use push, then normaly there are no such polling requests, but it uses some form of atmosphere or similar technology to send data back to the client when something need to be changed on the client display. So performance wise PUSH is better, but it's more sensitive to your servlet container/proxy/clients etc.